# ip addresses on Vlan

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan

I have a question maybe a dumb one but I got just started exploring VLAN's.
I got a vlan and I need to give it a IP address and I have two switches.
Can the IP addresses on the different switches be the same ip address like twice 172.10.15.1 or do i need to make one with 172.10.15.1 and 172.10.15.2

Comment: You do not address VLANs, you address interfaces. The router interface for the VLAN will need an address in the VLAN, and all hosts connected to the VLAN will need addresses in the VLAN for their interfaces connecting to the VLAN.

Comment: In any case, you cannot use the same address in a VLAN on multiple interfaces.

Comment: hey, thanks for your fast response, but i want to know if i am correct. i go to my vlan (interface vlan 100) then i write my ip address like here 172.10.15.1 and subnetmask then i give my computer the ip address 172.10.15.2 but can i give the vlan 100 on the second switch also the same ip address like on switch 1 or do i need to use 172.10.15.2 and give my computer then 172.10.15.3

Comment: Why do you want to put addresses on the SVIs? Layer-2 witches do not use IP addresses, except that managed switches can have a management address. In any case, you cannot duplicate addresses in a VLAN.

Comment: A layer 2 switch does not need IP addressing. The exception is if you want to manage it remotely you may give it an IP address. On a layer 3 switch you can assign IP addresses to switched virtual interfaces (SVI) which will allow you to route between VLANs on the switch rather than needing to go through an external router. So, are you trying to manage a switch remotely or route between VLANs?